# Getting "No signature of method:" error while updating the request xml using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

Trying to update request XML using groovy script. Error is coming on the last line. Below is the script:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

def request=testRunner.testCase.testSteps["SOAP Request - CurrencyCheck"].getPropertyValue("Request")


def groovyProgram=new XmlHolder(request)

def currency =testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("Currency")
def country = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("Name")

groovyProgram.setNodeValue("//web:CountriesUsingCurrency/web:sISOCurrencyCode",currency)

def newxml=groovyProgram.getXml()
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases("TC2_CurrencyCheck").testSteps("SOAP Request - CurrencyCheck").setPropertyValue("Request",newxml)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting specific test cases and test steps, you'd need to use the `get...ByName` methods. For example:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite
         .getTestCaseByName("TC2_CurrencyCheck")
         .getTestStepByName("SOAP Request - CurrencyCheck")
         .setPropertyValue("Request", newxml)
```

I assume you're also getting a similar error for your first statement `def request=testRunner.testCase.testSteps["SOAP Request...`